# Why can i not access the Figma API token with a http request?

Tags: javascript, api, figma

i am trying to acess the figma API using my personal token, but once i make the request it sends a response with the 403 status (forbidden), can someone help me ?

I generated a token: **My token**

I am making the request to the following url: 'https://api.figma.com/v1/files/${mytoken}';

The status code is the following: 403

What is wrong with my code? is the url wrong ?

```
    fetch('https://api.figma.com/v1/mytoken').then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
```

})

Status code: 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [figma authentication documentation](https://www.figma.com/developers/api#authentication) you should add the token to the header of the request.

```
X-Figma-Token: *YOUR TOKEN*
```

```
fetch('https://api.figma.com/v1/files/...', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-Figma-Token': 'your-figma-token',
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: {
  err: "Not found",
  status: 404
}

Comment: Seems like  i making the request to the wrong url

Comment: I already did follow the documentation.

Comment: Its strange,because once  i refresh the token, it says is being used everytime i am making a request...

Comment: It works for me, try another figma file id [image of fileid example](https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:1400/format:webp/1*rAIVZYPr_pbCUn7nzSebmQ.png) otherwise it perhaps sounds like your token is wrong somehow.

Comment: Nils Kahler, its working for me to, i was using the wrong endpoint. Good Coding!